# How to move/copy Issue as a project note in github

Tags: github

It is simple to copy project note into the Issues by pressing "Convert to issue" in note.

But how to copy Issues into the project notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right top corner of the Project page exists a button "Add Cards". 
Click to "Add Cards", it opens a list of issues. Just drag and drop Issue in to the any Column of the Project you want.